# Are compact constant mean curvature hypersurface sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am recently reading a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214444099). The author seems to use that (293 page) for $n\ge 2$, if $M^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ has constant mean curvature and $M^n$ is compact, then $M^n$ is sphere. But I google the constant mean curvature manifold, there are some constant mean curvature [tori](http://xueshu.baidu.com/s?wd=paperuri%3A%28918771b80571cba103296271f8d4701e%29&filter=sc_long_sign&tn=SE_xueshusource_2kduw22v&sc_vurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmathscinet-getitem%3Fmr%3D1014929&ie=utf-8&sc_us=1630497303744280806). What is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the notation $M^n \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ it is assumed that $M^n$ is embedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Then $M^n$ is the round sphere. This is proved by A. D. Alexandrov. See [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~ac/alan_chang_riem_geo_final_project.pdf).

For the classical dimension, the only CMC surface of genus $0$ in $\mathbb R^3$ is the round sphere. This is proved by H. Hopf. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369870/hopfs-theorem-on-cmc-surfaces). Assumptions on embeddedness is not needed.

Whether or not there exists CMC surface of higher genus was called Hopf conjecture and the first example was found by Wente. See [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102702809). The examples of course are not embedded.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean the examples are not embedded ?

Comment: The tori constructed by Wente are immersed and not embedded. @lanse7pty

Comment: Thanks, I always confuse embedded and immersed....